# Can I install wood floor on adhesive left from old linoleum floor?

Tags: flooring

We are installing about 100 ft.² of interlocking hardwood on the floor where the linoleum peeled off but the glue adhesive is still stuck on the floor. The floor is very level, and we tried scraping off some of the adhesive but it was taking forever. Can I simply lay the new hardwood on top of the old dried-up adhesive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as it is flat this should be a non-issue.  Floating or nailing down a little left-over adhesive is "normal" and not a big deal.

Comment: I would add that if you are floating the floor, it becomes more important to use an underlayment so that the floor can't stick to the adhesive. Having the floor stick in certain places but not others is a bad idea i.e. a floating floor needs to float.

Comment: @bobfandango - I was assuming old adhesive wasn't still that sticky on the surface.

Comment: Good point, Bob, even though the surface isn't sticky, something pressing into it would be. Nailed down real hardwood wouldn't care but snap-lock always gets an underlayment.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to remove the adhesive, lightly mist with water, let it sit for a few minutes, then scrape it up.